# Read the event log from another account C#

Tags: c#, remote-access, event-log

I have to develop an Audit C# application, which count the number of openings of each pdf file located in a folder. I've got a regular account on which I develop the application and a another one, which has access to data of the audit. So my question is: How can I access to the EventLogs of another account from my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use impersonation as described in  this article:
[How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)

Impersonate with different account and than use standard api to access Event Log.

Comment: It was my last solution, the others were: EventLogSession (but with this one, I wasn't able to connect to the machine) and WMI. Hope this one will work. Thank you ;)

Comment: Which LogonUser do you recommend?

Comment: You can use standard LoginUser from msdn - just specify LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE as you need only local access without network.

Comment: Isn't LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS better?

Comment: According to  MSDN documentation the difference is only in situations when you access network from  impersonated account.  So for your case -  you can use both of these logon types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made some test before and it worked well in both cases! It was a pleasure to talk with you, have a nice day! ;)